# Splitting HTML imports into two separate files , imports on 2nd file are not loading

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

My code is like this ,

index.html

```
<link rel="import" href="ele/applaunch.html">
<link rel="import" href="ele/applaunch2.html">
```

applaunch.html

```
<link rel="import" href="file1.html">
<link rel="import" href="file2.html">
<link rel="import" href="file3.html">
.
.
.
<link rel="import" href="file100.html">
```

applaunch2.html

```
<link rel="import" href="file101.html">
<link rel="import" href="file102.html">
<link rel="import" href="file103.html">
.
.
.
<link rel="import" href="file200.html">
```

After gulp build-prod , when I call index.html , imports of applaunch2.html are not getting loaded .
But if I move all import to applaunch.html then everything works fine .

Note - This problem occurs only in vulcanized build (after gulp build-prod) , non vulcanized build have no issues.

Folder Structure - src/index.html

```
               src/ele/applaunch.html


               src/ele/applaunch2.html
```

Thanks in advance , pardon me for errors.

Comment: Yes I am aware that its obsolete . I am planning to change it in near future . My gulp build only removes white spaces and comments . It works when I import everything in 1 file , but splitting into 2 files creates issue .

Comment: Please post the folder structure of your project. You're aware of how relative-paths work in subdirectories in HTML?